# lighttpd daemon failed to start after adding python support to read from cgi-bin

Tags: configuration, lighttpd, fastscroll, mod-fastcgi

getting python to run from cgi-bin causes lighttpd daemon failed to start

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/cgi-bin/" {
    alias.url += ( "/cgi-bin/" => "/var/www/cgi-bin" )
    cgi.assign = (".py" => "/usr/bin/python")
}
```

Am I doing something wrong
I also have below added in the beginning of `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`

```
server.modules = (
        "mod_indexfile",
        "mod_setenv",
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_redirect",
        "mod_cgi"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the lighttpd error log and review the trace for what you broke.

Alternatively, run lighttpd pre-flight tests on your config:
`lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`

Comment: I have decided not to use lighttpd